# Accessing file on network in java

Tags: java, mysql, networking

I'm working on a project that has two different parts. It's an e-voting system, so there's the part where voters vote, and there's the part where the admin can make changes like adding a new position, candidate, etc. I put these two parts in two different project folders called the client and the server. Each candidate has the URL of their picture, which is also stored on the server machine, which should be displayed to the client depending on which candidate is selected. The problem I'm having is how to read the picture from the server into the client application. Any tips on the best location to store the files such that I can pass just the server name as a parameter to the client and it's able to retrieve the file.

The application uses MySQL, and I'm so far assuming that the database server is the same as the application server.

Also, I was wondering of the possibility of storing the file in the database itself, and if so, how practical that would be in terms of speed.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using a framework (Struts 2, Spring, etc.) ?

Comment: I hope this is homework and not production code...

Comment: No, I'm not using any frameworks. And this is neither homework nor production code; I'm delivering it as a free application to my school and others who are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single point of information is helpful - so put the picts in the database, if possible. If you do it right, there is not more performance penalty than with other client-server-communication. If the client keeps running you can cache the pictures.

I haven't understood the two folder thing. The server folder must be synchronized to the client? Why? Why don't you store thinks like a new position in the database also?

Comment: The folders are just for coding in netbeans, i.e. they're different projects. So I don't require the folders to be synced. Also, everything is stored in the database, just that the picture is stored as the URL so that the application gets the file using the URL. So what I'm really asking is the best URL for the picture, so that the clients (which will be on multiple PCs, polling stations if you will) can all read this file. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I managed to get the pictures in the database perfectly using MySQL's Longblob and Java's Blob types. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use mySQL database but it's not designed to do that it might be slow, you can use **MongoDB with GridFS** or use some kind of file repository like **Apache Jackrabbit**.